# Python - I would like to create an empty data frame and name it using dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe

I am trying to create and name several data frames using dictionary keys as the names of the new data frames.

```
somedict = {'Apples': 50, 'Pears': 85, 'Cherries': 90}


for i in range(0,3):
     somedict[i] = pd.DataFrame()
```

I was hoping this would create three new data frames named Apples, Pears, Cherries. Unfortunately this just replaces the first three entries in somedict with empty dataframes.

Without a loop this would look like this:

```
Apples = pd.DataFrame()
Pears = pd.DataFrame()
Cherries = pd.DataFrame()
```

However, I would like to do this programatically without having to look at the dictionary and type out the keys as the names for the new dataframes.

If anyone knows how to do this dynamically it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: You can just make a new dictionary mapping those keys to empty Dataframes  `{k:pd.DataFrame() for k in somedict}`

Comment: @PatrickHaugh's solution will give you what you want, but usually you don't want to create empty DFs. It's better to collect data first and then to create a DataFrame using collected data. Try to avoid adding data to DataFrames row-by-row - it's one of the most inefficient methods. Just my $0.02...

Comment: Thanks for your comments, they were very helpful.   I understand that this method is something to be avoided, for now I need this solution to illustrate a concept. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I recognize that this method of dynamic table creation is not advisable.   However if anyone should run into this issue in the future, here is the code to create individual tables. There are probably more efficient ways to do this but I found this produced the intended results.

```
import pandas as pd

somedict = {'Apples': 50, 'Pears': 85, 'Cherries': 90}

somelist = list()
for k,v in somedict.iteritems():
    somelist.append(k)


for i in range(0,3):
     exec '%s=%s'%(str(somelist[i]), 'pd.DataFrame()')
```